# Why does my linux keep crashing?

Tags: debian, crash, stability

I am running Debian 6.0 Squeeze. Every half hour or so a dialog pops up on the side of my screen with the message -

> Kernel failure. A report has been sent to the developers to help them
>   fix the error. (Not the exact text but that's what it says)

Occasionally, say once a day it freezes and then reboots completely causing me to loose all my work.

What is happening?

Note - I used a USB stick and a Live Usb maker to install the system. Could that be a reason for the problem?

Comment: Probably installing from usb isn't a problem. In your case I would try to reinstall with different distro, and if problem stays I would check hardware. Have you checked the logs?

Comment: @blogger  No I haven't. Where are the logs? And what should I be looking for?

Comment: the most important log to look at for this kind of problem would be /var/log/kern.log.  Unfortunately, if the system freezes, the triggering event may not get logged or the log entries may not be written to disk.  remote syslogging to another machine on the network, a serial terminal, a line printer, or even a camera can be useful for capturing the log information.  As for what to look for, start looking for any error messages, mentions of drivers or hardware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some possibilities:

- As Alan suggested, bad memory is a common cause of problems.
- bad power-supplies can also cause random freezes and crashes.
- low-quality motherboard. either due to shoddy manufacturing or due to bad/dodgy parts (e.g. a sub-standard or cheap version of a NIC that claims to be a particular brand/model but isn't - the manufacturer's Windows driver may compensate for its inadequacies but the linux driver believes it is an XYZ device because that's what it claims to be)
- ditto for expansion cards

Are there any common patterns to the crashes? For example:

- does it happen more often when you do certain things or run particular programs (if so, what are they?)
- or after you've visited certain websites (e.g. badly written javascript code can leak memory like a sieve)
- or at a certain times of day (when?)
- or when other equipment is being operated nearby (e.g. a fridge motor turning on - a good UPS can protect against transient voltage fluctuations).

Answer (score 8):

I have noticed for some reason (and whether this is true or not, I'm not sure) that Linux is more sensitive to failing hardware.  I have seen this on my home office computer a couple of times.  Your best bet is to start running hardware diagnostics.

For that I would recommend [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/).  In your case, I would start with running a Memtest (at least for an hour), followed by a hard drive test (which test will depend on the brand of your hard drive).  Out of those two, I would bet a lot of money that something would show up defective - and my money would be on memory.

Comment: @AlanPhilips I have my system in dual boot with Windows 7 and it works just fine. So I doubt hardware would be the culprit. But I'll try that anyway.

Comment: I definitely would.  Mine was dual booting XP and Squeeze, and turned out to have a bad stick of memory.  Usually in a memtest, memory shows up bad after a few seconds - this one took 35 minutes to show up.  Thats why I suggested running it for at least an hour.  Good luck!

Comment: even an hour may not be enough.  i'd suggest leaving memtest running at least overnight.

Comment: @CraigSanders I would agree.

Answer (score 0):

If that dialog pops up and the system is still responding, you can run `dmesg` from a terminal to see the kernel's messages, which will show the error.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed when trying to run Linux from a USB flash drive that on some PC's (seems to be mostly older Dell's) that, after a while, something happens where the system thinks that the drive is disconnected, even though it is not physically disconnected.

I have an old Inspiron laptop, for example, where, after about a day or so running from a USB stick, this occurs and everything crashes because suddenly Linux can't find its root volume.

I didn't do enough troubleshooting to determine if it was the flash drive (a 4GB Kingston), the fact that it is a flash drive and not a USB-enclosed hard disk, etc. but have seen this on other Dell PCs.  I don't know if it's a subtle problem in the chipset the Linux drivers don't account for, some possible interaction with ACPI, or what.

Several years ago when I was using an old HP Pavillion as a server, I would have issues where USB attached drives would stop being recognized as connected.  Only physically disconnecting and reconnecting them would get them to be recognized by Linux again.  I was using a Belkin USB 2.0 PCI card at the time.  I've placed the same card in a Dell Poweredge 2500 and have run drives for months off of it with no issues.

You may try partitioning your hard drive, or installing a second hard drive in your system, and running Linux from that.